# Resizing images according to the Screen Size on Android

Tags: android, imageview, resize, android-framelayout

I am making a graphic intensive application for Android.

The problem i am facing is that on my home screen there are 6 images that are placed on a FrameLayout. Since i own a HTC Desire, I placed the images such that they look great on 3.7in but when i test it on a 5 or a 7in display, the UI goes crazy and there are huge gaps amongst the tiny images which were nice on 3.7in.

How do I fix my app for all screen sizes?
How do I scale the images such that there are no gaps?

please help ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look out this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in `Android Developers` from where you will get the exact answer. You have to create different images and put them in the respected folder's according to the `densities`.

Comment: great, I got the hang of it, thanks a million.

I just encountered another issue, since i am designing for target build Android 2.2 (API 8), it doesnt have support for xlargeScreens, which actually started from API 9. Is there a work around for this that while creating a 2.2 app i can design for xlargeScreens or i have to make two different projects aimed at different APIs